# Why does a socket be treated as closed when a single direction is closed in java?

Tags: java, sockets

sever code: **Server.java**

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8100);
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        {
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            System.out.println(new String(input.readAllBytes()));
            input.close();
        }
        {
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            String str = "pong";
            outputStream.write(str.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }

        server.close();
    }
}
```

client code: **Client.java**

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8100);
        {
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            String str = "ping";
            outputStream.write(str.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }
        {
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            System.out.println(new String(inputStream.readAllBytes()));
            inputStream.close();
        }
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

how to setup?

```
javac Server.java
javac Client.java
java Server
java Client
```

Description:

When the client is connected to the server, the expected behavior:

1. the client will send 'ping' to the server, and close its outputstream.
2. the server will receive 'ping', and close its inputstream
3. the server send 'pong' to the client, and close its outputstream, close the socket finally
4. the client will receive 'pong', and close its inputstream, close the socket finally

Server error behaviour:

```
ping
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
at java.base/java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java:962)
at Server.main(Server.java:17)
```

Client error behavior:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
at java.base/java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:923)
at Client.main(Client.java:18)
```

Why will a socket be treated as closed when only one direction of the socket is closed?

Comment: You are very kind.

Comment: Closing either the input stream or the output stream closes the other stream and the socket. You are confusing this with `shutdownOutput()` and `shutdownInput()`.